Salesforce Android SDK do not call onNewIntent method inside activity once I tap on notification
Salesforce Android SDK do not call onNewIntent  method inside activity once I tap on notification, it always call onCreate method even app is in foreground
Please find below code once I prepare Pending intent -
   val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.action = actionUri
            intent.putExtra(IS_WITH_IN_APP, java.lang.Boolean.parseBoolean(nid))
            intent.addCategory(PUSH_INAPP_KEY)
            val model = Build.MODEL
            return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                REQUEST_CODE,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )

and I have launched activity as singleTop, since It is working fine once I call notification from local

Open a support case. Also, can you please verify whether you are talking about the "Salesforce SDK" or the "Salesforce MobilePush SDK" as those are completely different products.
